# iOS / Android project organization to avoid duplicates

Tags: jira

I have noticed that in almost every app project for iOS and Android, there are two different projects, one for Android, one for iOS. This is good to track progress separately and assign tasks to different developers BUT leads to the duplication of user stories.

What I was thinking about is still to have separate iOS and Android projects but have user stories in Confluence. There would still be story tickets in JIRA (for platform progress tracking purposes), but they would link to Confluence for their content. Platform specific content could still be attached to / linked from the tickets (e.g attach a design or link to Zeplin).

The benefit would be to have user stories in one place only. Also, ATLASSIAN provides [integration between JIRA and Confluence](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/use-jira-applications-and-confluence-together-427623543.html).

What are your thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a shared board instead.

By default, JIRA Projects and boards are 1-1.

But there's no requirement to keep that default.

Every board is a filter. Instead of having one board with filter 'Project = "A"' and another with 'Project = "B"', have a single filter (and board) with 'Project = "A" OR Project = "B"'.

Then all user stories may be visualized on a single board, with separate subtasks for iOS and Android. You can use Quick Filters to allow your developers to hide irrelevant issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should use components to resolve this issue, if you already use them to model your project specific components maybe you can distinct the OS,there may be components only available in just one OS.
For example if you have

- UI
- Services
- DB

You can Have

- ANDROID UI,IOS-UI
- Services, IOS-Specific services
- DB

Then in your issues for example user stories, you can set which components are affected.
If this has to be developed twice you can clone issues to track each one of them apart.